# Changing an attibute of Laravel Eloquent collection changes every reference

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, collections

Here's my scenario.
I have a relationship between subscription and product. Every subscription belongs to some product and I have defined relationships.

Now if I do this:
`Subscription::with(['product', 'address'])->get();`
I will get all subscriptions with product.

Product have attibutes like shipping_price, price etc.

Now if I change shipping_price of a product within a subscription, it changes shipping_price for that product inside all subscriptions (This comes in handy manier times but this time I dont want this change to reflect everywhere).

For example:

```
$subscriptions = Subscription::with('product')->get();
foreach ($subscriptions as $item) {
   $item->product->shipping_price = ShippingService::getShippingPrice($item->product->key, $item->product->shipping_price, $item->address->zip);
}
```

This will change shipping_price for every product having same ID within those subscriptions.

My requirement is to stop this behavior at this one place. So if I change one attribute, it doesnt change others.

I know one way to query again with loop and dont get products using eager loading but that will be slow.

Thanks.

Comment: if you have a conditional property, why don't you pull up the shipping_price on the Subscription and return the $item->product->shipping_price that way in the same getter you could add a call to the conditional to see if you want the product's shipping_price or your own

Comment: Can you include an example condition, could it be like if ($subscription->type === 'sub1') {}?

Comment: @mrhn Yes. Actually I dont have a condition exactly. I have a function which returns shipping price and then I update this attibute. For example, `$item->product->shipping_price = somefunction(parameters);` But it changes shipping_price for that product for every subscription.

Comment: @mrhn I have updated that part.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a custom property "real_shipping_price" to this product Model with an accessor getRealShippingPriceAttribute (using your ShippingService).

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json for example.

Comment: Consider I have a parameter that has no relation with model. How can I do that then?